# (MC bukkit server) Right-clicking with specific item to trigger an event

Tags: java, eclipse, server, minecraft, bukkit

```
public void arrowstick(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        Player p = event.getPlayer();
            if(p.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getType().equals(Material.STICK)){
                if(event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK){

                Arrow ar = p.getWorld().spawn(p.getLocation(), Arrow.class);
                ar.setShooter(p);


                }

            }

    }
```

What I want to do here is shoot out an arrow if the player right-clicks with a stick in his hands. I cant seem to find a solution for this, does anyone have an idea about what I might be doing wrong? Im sorry if its a small and dumb mistake, its currently 2 am here so yeah, hope you guys can help

Comment: I can't test it from here so just as a comment, but `p.launchProjectile(Arrow.class);`should do. Or if you want to stick to your method you'll need `ar.setVelocity(p.getEyeLocation().getDirection().multiply(2));` (you can change the multiplier to whatever you need)

Comment: @dly Alright thanks first of all, it worked but theres still a small problem: your setvelocity doesnt seem to work, the newly spawned arrow just directly drop to the ground, how do I fix that? https://pastebin.com/ESZbVCWL

Comment: What do you get if you output the arrow's Velocity before changing it? Also it might be a good idea to have a look at `Vector`s. This way you could as well make use of Player's `getLocation().getDirection()`

Comment: @dly How would I do that? (some var) equals a.getVelocity and print it out? Also how would I be able to include Vectors into this concept? By the way what I noticed is that its spawning the arrows inside of me because we took the player location to launch the arrow, how could we make it spawn in front of me?

Comment: Alright ignore the first two questions in my comment above, I got what you were trying to do. Heres what comes out if I print out `Vector speed = a.getVelocity();` http://imgur.com/a/HVozu

Comment: Vectors and stuff are that kind of maths I can't solve without enough coffee..  try something like this `Location arrowSpawn = p.getEyeLocation().toVector().add(p.getEyeLocation().getDirection().multiply(2)).toLocation(p.getWorld())` or have a look at this: https://bukkit.org/threads/tutorial-how-to-calculate-vectors.138849/ (this uses some deprecated methods, but the general idea is good)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I coded it for you here:

```
public class Arrow extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    public void onEnable() {
        this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        if (p.getInventory().getItemInHand().getType() == Material.STICK) {
            if (e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
                p.launchProjectile(Arrow.class);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If you just copy the listener in a new class dont forget to make it a `implements Listener` and to register the Listener.